# JS - Access a <table> from the DOM (error: "TypeError: tablex[0] is undefined")

Tags: javascript, dom, html-table

I want to add `<th>` headers to a `<table>` that does not have an `"id"` but which is in a `<div>` having a known `"id"` so I traverse the DOM to find it:

```
// search <table>
var c = document.getElementById("tablediv").children; 
var i; for(i = 0; i < c.length; i++) 
   { Output("- " + c[i].nodeName + "<br>"); // show progress
     if(c[i].nodeName == "TABLE") break; }

var tablex = c[i]; // that's the right object
var columns = tablex[0].length; // "TypeError: tablex[0] is undefined"
var row = tablex.insertRow(-1);
for(var i = 0; i < columns; i++) 
{  var headerCell = document.createElement("TH");
   headerCell.innerHTML = tablex[1][i];
   row.appendChild(headerCell);
}
```

And when `tablex[0].length;` is run it raises ***"TypeError: tablex[0] is undefined"***.

I guess `var tablex` is an incorrect way to assign `c[i];`.

Can you please let me know how to do it right?

NOTE: the first TD row of the table contains the column titles so either we convert this row to TH or we fetch titles and delete the TD row after a TH row was inserted.

Comment: I can't post the HTML showing the TABLE because it is generated by a script in the "tablediv" DIV (pressing CTRL+U to get the source won't show it).

Comment: If it was me, I'd just set the table's `innerHTML`.

Comment: @Jenna, it looks like a NICE idea, thank you! I will try that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First of all, you don't need to traverse like that. It's easier to query the table directly with `querySelector('#tablediv table')`. Notice the use of querySelector instead of querySelectorAll, this returns first table inside the node with requested ID.
So the final code would look like this:

```
var table = document.querySelector('#tablediv table');
// Here you can add check if the table was found (not null) - I'll leave that to you
var firstRow = table.querySelector('tr');
var columns = firstRow.querySelectorAll('td'); // Or th if you have a header cells
console.log(`Number of columns: ${columns.length}`);

var headerRow = document.createElement('tr');
firstRow.parentNode.insertBefore(headerRow, firstRow);


for(var i = 0; i < columns.length; i++) {
  var headerCell = document.createElement("TH");
  headerCell.innerHTML = columns[i].innerHTML;
  headerRow.appendChild(headerCell);
}
firstRow.remove();
```

Comment: GREAT answer, thank you. But with your way of doing things my code adding TH headers won't work... could you help with this too?

Comment: I though `querySelector` was experimental?

Comment: You want to insert header for each column in the table? Meaning your table does not have th and you want to add a row at the beginning with th for each column?

Comment: @Pseudohuman noup, read the docs at https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector all major browsers support it.

Comment: @Goran.it - Yes! That's exactly what I want to do - alternatively, I could transform the first row from TD to TH elements (the text values are right).

Comment: I've updated the answer, added the dynamic injection of the header row / cells. You still need to change the text inside them as I'm not sure what you have in your table.

Comment: @Goran.it - FAN-TAS-TIC! You have been of great help in a timely fashion. Thank you again Goran.

Comment: @Goran - the TH text is the text of the first TD row (whihch has to be erased then).

Comment: You can extract that with `headerCell.innerHTML = firstRow.querySelector('td:nth-of-type(' + i + ')').innerHTML` - Not tested but it should work.. And afterwards to delete the previous first row you just need to add : `firstRow.remove()`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/197451/discussion-between-gil-and-goran-it).

Answer (score 0):

Considering the fact that `tablex` would optimally be a HTMLTableElement, `tablex[0]` is not defined.

Comment: @Gil please check the docs for [HTMLTableElement](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLTableElement). HTMLTableElement is not an array and so `tablex[0]` will be undefined.

Comment: That's great to know why it fails, but again, this does not explain how to do it right.